# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Value is not of type 'long'

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to create a little video game. I'm using P5.min.js for the canva but i can't find out the error.
It said it's on my p5.min.js files : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Value is not of type 'long'.

I tried to replace p5.min.js by the CDN but nothing change.

There is my code :

```
let cols, rows;
let w = 90;
let grid = [];
let stack = [];
let grenouille;

// Récuperation images
function preload(){
    sac = loadImage("img/sac-bb-rond.png");
    grenouille = loadImage("img/grenouillecanvas.png");
    chinois = loadImage("img/usine_mechant.png");
}








// déplacement mobile
window.onload = function () {
    let pozx1;
    let pozy1;
    let pozx;
    let pozy;
    let html = document.querySelector("#html");
    
    // mettre les questions dans le tableau
    setAvailableQuestions();
    // call une question
    getNewQuestion();


    html.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
        e=e || window.event;

        // x = horizontal
        pozx = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        pozy = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;

        
    })
    
    html.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
        e=e || window.event;

        // x = horizontal
        pozx1 = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        pozy1 = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
        horizontal = pozx1 - pozx;
        vertical = pozy1 - pozy;

        // aller à droite
        if(horizontal > vertical && horizontal > 50){
            // console.log("go droite");
            goRight()
        }
        // aller à gauche
        else if(horizontal < vertical && horizontal < -50){
            // console.log("go gauche");
            goLeft()
        }
        // aller en bas
        else if(vertical > horizontal && vertical > 50){
            // console.log("go bas");
            goDown()
            
        }
        // aller en haut
        else if(vertical < horizontal && vertical < -50){
            // console.log("go haut");
            goUp()
        }
    })
}
//








function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
    cols = floor(width/w);
    rows = floor(height/w);
    canvas.center();
    // vitesse de carrés violets
    // frameRate(1);

    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++){
            let cell = new Cell(i,j);
            grid.push(cell);
        }
    }
    current = grid[0];

    goal = grid[cols * rows - 1];

    // ennemi = grid[(cols * rows - 1) / 2];

    ennemi = grid[floor((cols * rows / 2 - 1) )];
    
}
// derniere case
// grid[168]

function draw(){
    background(51);
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        grid[i].show();
    }

    current.visited = true;
    // current.show();
    current.highlight();
    // current = image(grenouille, 10, 6, 20, 20);

    goal.objectif();

    ennemi.zone();
    
    // ETAPE 1
    let next = current.checkNeighbors();
    if(next){
        
        next.visited = true;

        // ETAPE 2
        stack.push(current);

        // ETAPE 3
        removeWalls(current, next);

        // ETAPE 4
        current = next;
    }
    else if(stack.length > 0){
        current = stack.pop();
    }
}

function index(i, j){
    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols-1 || j > rows-1){
        return -1;
    }
    return i + j * cols;
}

function Cell(i, j){
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    //            top  right bottom  left 
    this.walls = [true, true, true , true];
    this.visited = false;
    this.checkNeighbors = function() {
        let Neighbors = []
        let top = grid[index(i, j-1)];
        let right = grid[index(i+1, j)];
        let bottom = grid[index(i, j+1)];
        let left = grid[index(i-1, j)];

        if(top && !top.visited){
            Neighbors.push(top);
        }
        if(right && !right.visited){
            Neighbors.push(right);
        }
        if(bottom && !bottom.visited){
            Neighbors.push(bottom);
        }
        if(left && !left.visited){
            Neighbors.push(left);
        }
        if(Neighbors.length > 0){
            let rand = floor(random(0, Neighbors.length));
            return Neighbors[rand];
        }
        else{
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    this.checkVoisins = function() {
        let voisins = []
        let top = grid[index(i, j-1)];
        let right = grid[index(i+1, j)];
        let bottom = grid[index(i, j+1)];
        let left = grid[index(i-1, j)];

        if(top && !this.walls[0]){
            voisins.push(top);
        }
        if(right && !this.walls[1]){
            voisins.push(right);
        }
        if(bottom && !this.walls[2]){
            voisins.push(bottom);
        }
        if(left && !this.walls[3]){
            voisins.push(left);
        }
        if(voisins.length > 0){
            let randoms = floor(random(0, voisins.length));
            return voisins[randoms];
        }
        else{
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    //  carré actif
    this.highlight = function(){
        let x = this.i*w;
        let y = this.j*w;
        noStroke();
        image(grenouille, x, y, w, w);
        // bg de la grenouille
        // fill(51, 51, 51, 10000);
        // rect(x, y, w, w);
    }

    this.objectif = function(){
        let x = this.i*w;
        let y = this.j*w;
        noStroke();
        image(sac, x, y, w, w);
    }

    this.zone = function(){
        let x = this.i*w;
        let y = this.j*w;
        noStroke();
        image(chinois, x, y, w, w);
    }

    this.show = function() {
        let x = this.i*w;
        let y = this.j*w;
        stroke("black");
        // épaisseur des murs
        strokeWeight(8);
        if(this.walls[0]){
            line(x,y,x+w,y);
        }
        if(this.walls[1]){
            line(x+w,y,x+w,y+w);
        }
        if(this.walls[2]){
            line(x+w,y+w,x,y+w);
        }
        if(this.walls[3]){
            line(x,y+w,x,y);
        }

        if (this.visited){
            noStroke();
            fill(255, 0, 255, 100);
            rect(x, y ,w ,w);
        }
    }
}

function removeWalls(a, b){
    let x = a.i - b.i;
    if(x === 1){
        a.walls[3] = false;
        b.walls[1] = false;
    }
    else if(x === -1){
        a.walls[1] = false;
        b.walls[3] = false;
    }

    let y = a.j - b.j;
    if(y === 1){
        a.walls[0] = false;
        b.walls[2] = false;
    }
    else if(y === -1){
        a.walls[2] = false;
        b.walls[0] = false;
    }
}


// Déplacement dans le labyrinthe
let n = 0;
let t = 0;


function goUp(){
    if(t > 0 && !current.walls[0]){
        current = grid[index(n, t-1)];
        t = t - 1;

        let suite = ennemi.checkVoisins();
        if(suite){
            ennemi = suite;
        }

        // alerte victoire
        if(current == grid[cols * rows - 1]){
            alert("Vous avez gagné")
        }

        // alerte défaite
        if(current == ennemi){
            alert("Vous avez perdu")
        }
    }
}

function goRight(){

    if(n < cols-1 && !current.walls[1]){
        current = grid[index(n+1, t)];
        n = n + 1;
        
        let suite = ennemi.checkVoisins();
        if(suite){
            ennemi = suite;
        }

        // alerte victoire
        if(current == grid[cols * rows - 1]){
            alert("Vous avez gagné")
        }

        // alerte défaite
        if(current == ennemi){
            alert("Vous avez perdu")
        }
    }
}

function goDown(){
    if(t < rows-1 && !current.walls[2]){
        current = grid[index(n, t+1)];
        t = t + 1;

        // déplacement random chinois
        let suite = ennemi.checkVoisins();
        if(suite){
            ennemi = suite;
        }

        // alerte victoire
        if(current == grid[cols * rows - 1]){
            alert("Vous avez gagné")
        }

        // alerte défaite
        if(current == ennemi){
            alert("Vous avez perdu")
        }

    }
}

function goLeft(){
    if(n > 0 && !current.walls[3]){
        current = grid[index(n-1, t)];
        n = n - 1;

        let suite = ennemi.checkVoisins();
        if(suite){
            ennemi = suite;
        }

        // alerte victoire
        if(current == grid[cols * rows - 1]){
            alert("Vous avez gagné")
        }

        // alerte défaite
        if(current == ennemi){
            alert("Vous avez perdu")
        }
    }
}

// déplacement ordinateur
window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);

function doKeyDown(evt)
        {
            switch (evt.keyCode) {
                case 38:  /* Up arrow was pressed */
                    goUp();
                    break;

                case 40 :  /* Down arrow was pressed */
                    goDown();
                    break;

                case 37:  /* Left arrow was pressed */
                    goLeft();
                    break;

                case 39:  /* Right arrow was pressed */
                    goRight();
                    break;
            }
}




// Quiz random question
const questionText = document.querySelector(".question-text")
const optionContainer = document.querySelector(".option-container")
// const button = document.querySelector("#button")

let questionCounter = 0;
let currentQuestion;
let availableQuestions = [];
let availableOptions = [];

// push questions in availableQuestions array
function setAvailableQuestions(){
    const totalQuestion = quiz.length;
    for(let i =0; i<totalQuestion; i++){
        availableQuestions.push(quiz[i])
    }
}



function getNewQuestion(){
    // numero de question
    // questionNumber.innerHTML = "question " + (questionCounter+1) + " sur " + quiz.length;

    // set question text
    const questionIndex = availableQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length)]
    currentQuestion = questionIndex;
    questionText.innerHTML = currentQuestion.q;
    
    const index1 = availableQuestions.indexOf(questionIndex);
    // retirer la question de questionIndex pour ne pas la répéter
    availableQuestions.splice(index1,1);

    const optionLen = currentQuestion.options.length
    
    for(let i = 0; i< optionLen; i++){
        availableOptions.push(i)
    }
    for(let i = 0; i< optionLen; i++){
        // random option
        const optonIndex = availableOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableOptions.length)];
        // précup optionIndex dans availableOptions
        const index2 = availableOptions.indexOf(optonIndex);
        // enleve optionIndex de availableOptions no repeat
        availableOptions.splice(index2, 1);
        console.log(optonIndex);
        const option = document.createElement("p");
        option.innerHTML = currentQuestion.options[optonIndex];
        option.id = optonIndex;
        option.className = "option";
        optionContainer.appendChild(option);
        option.setAttribute("onclick", "get(this)");
    }
    questionCounter++
}


// changement de la class
function get(element){
    document.getElementById(0).className = document.getElementById(0).className.replace(/(?:^|s)option correct(?!S)/g, 'option');
    document.getElementById(1).className = document.getElementById(1).className.replace(/(?:^|s)option correct(?!S)/g, 'option');
    document.getElementById(2).className = document.getElementById(2).className.replace(/(?:^|s)option correct(?!S)/g, 'option');
    document.getElementById(3).className = document.getElementById(3).className.replace(/(?:^|s)option correct(?!S)/g, 'option');
    element.classList.add("correct")
}
function test(){
    const activeAnswer = document.querySelector(".correct");

    console.log(activeAnswer.id);
    if(currentQuestion.answer == activeAnswer.id){
        console.log("correct");
    }
}

// window.onload = function(){
//     // mettre les questions dans le tableau
//     setAvailableQuestions();
//     // call une question
//     getNewQuestion();
// }
```

And there is the error in the console :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get` in your `onclick` handler isn't your own `function get(element)` it's P5.js's one: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get

Rename your function to something else, like `getElem`, and don't set `onevent` attributes, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, 
I changed the function "get" to "getElem" as you said, but I don't find out what you call "one event", can you give me the line please ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "`onevent` attribute", not "one event" :-). Replace `option.setAttribute("onclick", "get(this)");` with `option.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { getElem(this); });`

Comment: Not all hero wear a cape. Thank you so much !